# Missing "Formatting Options" in properties window in Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-framework, visual-studio

The name is pretty self explanatory. I have Microsoft Visual Studios LightSwitch 2011 and I can't find the "Formatting Options" for a table's field. In the properties window I only have the following categories:

- General
- Appearance
- Validation

I'm attempting to follow this tutorial:

- [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bethmassi/beginning-lightswitch-in-vs-2012-part-1-whats-in-a-table-describing-your-data)

(About half way through the article it tells you to go to "Formatting" and mine doesn't have this option for some reason.) Can anyone help me figure out whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at a tutorial for Lightswtich 2012, not 2011.

The LS2011 version of the same article is linked in the 2012 version you linked.

> NOTE: This is an update of an article written against Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 that has been updated for LightSwitch in Visual Studio 2012.

The [2011 version is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bethmassi/beginning-lightswitch-part-1-whats-in-a-table-describing-your-data) and unlike the 2012 version, there's no mention of "Formatting", as that menu is different in 2011 vs. 2012:

2012's version of the menu:

[image: LS2012 Menu]

2011's version of the menu:

[image: LS2011 Menu]

Comment: Oh ok, I remember reading that VS2012 just integrated lightswitch 2011 without updates. Thanks for the info.

Comment: No problem, I hope the 2011 version of the tutorial works out for you. :)